# Prevent model saving before formset validation

Tags: django, django-forms

How can i prevent model saving before formset validation ? Code exemple:

```
form = StockMovementForm(data=data)
Formset = inlineformset_factory(StockMovement, StockMovement.products.through, extra=2, can_delete=False)
if form.is_valid():
  stock_movement = form.save()
  formset = Formset(data=data, instance=stock_movement)
  if formset.is_valid():
    formset.save()
```

(StockMovementForm is used to **create** a new *stock_movement*)

I would like save **form** after check validity of **formset**.

I found something like:

```
form = StockMovementForm(data=data)
Formset = inlineformset_factory(StockMovement, StockMovement.products.through, extra=2, can_delete=False)
formset = Formset(data=data)
if form.is_valid():
  if formset.is_valid():
    stock_movement = form.save()
    objects = formset.save(commit=False)
    for object in objects:
      object.movement = stock_movement
      object.save()
```

But i don't know if it's a good way (found [here](http://yergler.net/blog/2009/09/27/nested-formsets-with-django/)).

Comment: are you editing an existing instance of `stock_movement` or creating a new one?

Comment: It's a new stock_movement object. I edit the question for that detail.

Comment: Hmm. You need an instance of the related model when using inline formsets...what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm creating a stock_movement with some related (manyToMany) stock_movement_product. So if an error is found in formset of stock_movement_product, stock_movement id already created by form.save().

Comment: Added an internet found in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would check for validity of the form and the formsets as such:

```
form = StockMovementForm(data=data)
Formset = inlineformset_factory(StockMovement,
    StockMovement.products.through, extra=2, can_delete=False)
formset = Formset(data=data)
if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
    stock_movement = form.save()
    objects = formset.save(commit=False)
    for object in objects:
      object.movement = stock_movement
      object.save()
```